# Matrix representation of Fractional Linear Transformation and the Identity Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, define the fractional linear transformation of $x$ as $f(x)$ where:

$$f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx+d}$$

Then $f(x)$ has a matrix representation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $F$ where:

$$F = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$

Then the function $g(x)= \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ has the matrix representation of:

$$G = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Observe that $g(g(g(x)))=x$. Then why isn't $G^3=I$ ? In fact:

$$G^3 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = -I$$

How does that make sense where $g^3(x)=x$ and not $-x$ ? Shouldn't the vector

$$ v=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$ get mapped back to itself after 3 iterations of multiplying by $G$ ? What am I missing?

Comment: I want to add one suggestion to your otherwise great question: you might want to replace $v = \pmatrix{x\\y}$ with $v = \pmatrix{a\\b}$, as you've already used $x$ to mean some real number elsewhere. There's nothing *wrong* with what you wrote, but it's potentially confusing.

Comment: Note that $$f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} =  \frac{\lambda ax+\lambda b}{\lambda cx+\lambda d} $$ with $\lambda \ne 0$ of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

For which matrices $M = \pmatrix{a & b\\ c & d}$ is $f_M(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx+d}$ the identity function? You know that it is when $M = I$, but is that the *only* matrix? No. For instance, $M = 2I$ also produces a function $f_{2I}$ that's the identify function. The mapping $M \mapsto f_M$ from matrices to fractional linear transformations is not injective.

Comment: Awesome! More specifically to my question, it's instructive to note that $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ can be written in two main ways: $g_1(x)=\dfrac{0x+1}{-1x+1}$ and $g_2(x)=\dfrac{0x-1}{1x-1}$. The latter results in: 
$$G_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ where ${G_2}^3=I$

Comment: Terrific! (And this discovery is rather more general ... you might want to think about just how you might generalize it.)